# Add WordPress Core CSS into editor-style.css

Tags: css, tinymce, editor

I am using a custom child theme (from Parabola, [Cryout Creations](https://www.cryoutcreations.eu/), lastest version), but it seems that the `editor-style.css` file is not up-to-date. Rather than rewriting everything, I would like it to contain every css used on the front-end, so TinyMCE looks as close as the published page/article (this is important).

In order to do that, I have created a new editor-style.css file in my child theme, so it overrides the not-up-to-date file. So far, it includes the styles.css file from my theme, but it lacks a lot of CSS from WordPress Core (the one on line 60 on the index file : [http://nouveau.domaineloupia.com](http://nouveau.domaineloupia.com/)).

So, how to add this “core CSS” to my `editor-style.css` file ? And would it be the best way to do this ? I have seen many stuff talking about the `add_editor_style` function, but I do not know if I could use it to do what I want nor how.

how can i do this?

Comment: you want to add your styles in admin dashboard?

Comment: Well, only on pages with the TinyMCE editor would be best, but why not if I cannot do so otherwise.

Comment: Well, you can load your css file in admin area through [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) tell me if you want me show you how can you load your css file in admin area

Comment: From the exemple I can see how to load custom CSS on the admin pages, but since I don't know how to find the "WordPress core CSS" file, I cannot use this.

Comment: i am bit confuse from your question, what i understand is : your TinyMCE style file is not updated and you created a new css file name "**editor-style.css**" with all styles, now you want to totally replace tinymce style file with your newly created file, Right?

Comment: Not exactly, so far in my **editor-syle.css** file I only have the content of the **style.css** from my theme, but I still lack the CSS from WordPress, which are directly written on my index page (line 60), and do not seems to be overrided by **style.css**

Answer (score 0):

To add styles that affect TinyMCE you need to do the following:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'editor_styles' );
function editor_styles() {
       add_editor_style( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'editor-style.css' );
}
```

Basically it will load a editor-style.css file located in the root of your child theme.